# UIPopoverController not sizing correctly in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uipopovercontroller

Prior to iOS 8 my app using UIPopoverController was working fine. I had it anchored and opening up at a size of 400 x 215. However now when i run my app on iPad using iOS 8 my popover window is not sized properly.  Its almost popping up at the full height and width off my anchor. Since iOS is so new i can't seem to find an adjustment for this. Below is my code:

```
UIView *anchor = self.personAnchor;
        UIViewController *viewControllerForPopover =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"choosePersonViewController"];


        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                   initWithContentViewController:viewControllerForPopover];
        popover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(400, 215);
        popover.delegate = self;
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:anchor.frame
                                 inView:anchor.superview
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: Set the view controller's `preferredContentSize` instead of setting the popover's `popoverContentSize`.

Comment: on the view controller itself?  the choosePersonViewController?

Comment: On the view controller you will show in the popover - `viewControllerForPopover`.

Comment: and where is that setting to set the preferredContentSize?

Comment: What do you mean by "where is that setting"? Look it up in the docs. It's a `UIViewController` property.

Answer (score 5):

Set the view controller's `preferredContentSize` instead of setting the popover's `popoverContentSize` - copied from comment